# как посчитать количество событий в файле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Имеется файл вида:

```
[2018-05-17 01:55:52.665804] NOK
[2018-05-17 01:56:23.665804] OK
[2018-05-17 01:56:55.665804] OK
[2018-05-17 01:57:16.665804] NOK
[2018-05-17 01:57:58.665804] OK
...
```

Напишите программу, которая считывает файл
и выводит число событий NOK за каждую минуту

```
[2018-05-17 01:57] 1234
[2018-05-17 01:58] 4321
```

как это вообще можно сделать?
хоть в какую сторону двигаться?

```
with open(file_name, mode='r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if 'NOK' in line:
            print(line)
```

Comment: Надо всегда следить за отступами, когда постишь код. В питоне это критически важно, иногда невозможно понять из контекста, где кончается блок, если автор не уследил за этим. Здесь понятно, но так бывает не всегда.

Comment: Наличие NOK вы смогли определить, осталось группировать сообщения по времени :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делаем парсер:

1. Вытаскивание даты до минут включительно

   - Я делал через [регулярные выражения](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), но можно попробовать через [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)
   - Работает так: `[2018-05-17 01:55:52.665804]` -> `2018-05-17 01:55`
2. Сбор и подсчет строк с одинаковой датой из шага **1.**
3. Вывод результата

**text.txt**:

```
[2018-05-17 01:55:52.665804] NOK
[2018-05-17 01:55:55.665804] NOK
[2018-05-17 01:55:56.665804] NOK
[2018-05-17 01:56:23.665804] OK
[2018-05-17 01:56:55.665804] OK
[2018-05-17 01:57:16.665804] NOK
[2018-05-17 01:57:58.665804] OK
```

Пример:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

file_name = 'text.txt'
pattern_datetime = re.compile('\[(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}).+\]')
date_by_counter = defaultdict(int)

with open(file_name) as file:
    for line in file:
        if 'NOK' not in line:
            continue

        match = pattern_datetime.search(line)
        # Проверка, что регулярка смогла найти дату
        if match:
            date_str = match.group(1)  # Получение даты
            date_by_counter[date_str] += 1

for k, v in date_by_counter.items():
    print(f'[{k}] {v}')
```

Результат:

```
[2018-05-17 01:55] 3
[2018-05-17 01:57] 1
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Logs:

    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file = None
        self.date = None
        self.lines = None
        self.count_nok = None
        self.file_content = None
        self.file_name_logs = None
        self.file_name = file_name

    def open_and_clear_file(self):
        self.file = open(self.file_name, mode='w+')
        self.file_content = self.file.read()
        self.file.write('')
        self.file.close()

    def open_and_write_file(self):
        self.file_name = 'out1.txt'
        self.file = open(self.file_name, mode='a')
        self.file_content = f'{self.date} {self.count_nok}\n'
        self.file.write(self.file_content)
        self.file.close()

    def file_read(self):
        self.file_name_logs = 'events.txt'
        self.count_nok = 0
        self.date = []
        self.open_file_and_sorted()

    def open_file_and_sorted(self):
        with open(self.file_name_logs, 'r', encoding='cp1251') as file:
            file_contents = file.readlines()
            file_contents.sort(key=lambda line: (line.split(' ')[0]), reverse=False)
            self.append_in_list(file_contents)

    def append_in_list(self, file_contents):
        for line in file_contents:
            if 'NOK' not in line:
                continue
            elif line[1:17] in self.date:
                self.count_nok += 1
            elif line[1:17] not in self.date:
                self.write_file(line)

    def write_file(self, line):
        if self.count_nok > 0:
            self.open_and_write_file()
            self.count_reload()
            self.date[0] = (line[1:17])
        else:
            self.count_reload()
            self.date.append(line[1:17])

    def count_reload(self):
        self.count_nok = 0
        self.count_nok += 1

    def write_file_close(self):
        self.open_and_write_file()


logs = Logs(file_name='out1.txt')
logs.open_and_clear_file()
logs.file_read()
logs.write_file_close()
```